# How to read MongoDB nested arrays into local memory

Tags: java, database, mongodb

I've put a `HashMap<String, Set<Long>>` object into a MongoDB document under "disabled_channels" but I can't figure out how to retrieve it and turn it back into a `HashMap<String, Set<Long>>` object in local memory. I'm usually very good at reading in lists, individual values, etc, with something like `found.getList("disabled_commands", String.class)` but I'm really lost on how to approach this.

[image]

```
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = bot.getDataManager().getConfig();
    Document config = new Document("guild", guild.getIdLong());
    Document found = collection.find(config).first();
    // I get lost here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Document` itself is a `map` implementation internally. [Reference](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/javadoc/org/bson/Document.html)

You need to use [get](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/javadoc/org/bson/Document.html#get-java.lang.Object-) function on `found` document and cast it to `Document` as below

```
Document channels = (Document)found.get("disabled_channels")
```

Then you can access elements in `channels` using the same `get` method and cast it as per the need.